Proof that the angular measure is a measure.
Let $\mathbb{S}^1=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2: \lvert x \rvert=1\}$. Consider $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{S}^1)=\{B\cap\mathbb{S}^1:B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)\}$. I want to prove that there exists a measure on $\mu$ $(\mathbb{S}^1,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{S}^1))$, such that if $B\in  \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{S}^1)$ is an arch, then $\mu(B)$ is its angle. So we must for example have $\mu(\mathbb{S}^1)=2\pi$. This statement is from my lecture notes.
What is the easiest way of prove this? I was thinking of defining the algebra of disjoint (closed, open?) archs and definiting a function to be the sum of its archs, then showing it is a premeasure and then using Carathéodory's extension theorem. I think it is not difficult to show that it is an algebra, but I don't know how to show that it is a premeasure.
Is this proved somewhere, could you please provide a link if so? Or is there a quicker way of getting the result than constructing the measure?

Do you know how to prove the existence of the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$?

@CJDowd I have seen the proof of that.

Starting with the canonical measure space $([0,1),\mathcal{B}([0,1)),m)$, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure, the arc measure (or rather the normalized arc measure) may be obtained by the push-forward of the map $f:[0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$
$f(t)=e^{2\pi it}$. Clearly $f$ is $\mathcal{B}([0,1))-\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{S}^1))$ measurable. And $\nu:=m\circ f^{-1}$ is a rotation invariant Borel measure on $\mathbb{S}^1$.  Notice that $2\pi\nu(\cdot)$ is the arc-measure (or angular measure as described by the OP)
